# how to write C# equivalent code corresponding to this XAML code for customizing selected treeviewItem color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
 </TreeView.Resources>
```

Actually , i m having a TreeView in WPF App, as it contains various TreeViewItems , when I drag a treeview Item to DataGrid , that TreeViemItem gets grayed.

As i haven't used XAML to create that treeview , I used C# code so I want to fix it using C# code only.

```
TreeView treeNode = new TreeView();

//In some loop
TreeViewItem childTreeNode = new TreeViewItem();
childTreeNode.Header = "Item 1";
childTreeNode.ToolTip = "File Path";

childTreeNode.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
childTreeNode.Background = Brushes.White;

treeNode.Items.Add(childTreeNode);
//End Loop
```

Now few TreeView Items get added into this TreeView.
Tree Looks fine but once focus removed from tree it's selected treeviewitem got grayed

Refer this question also
[How to Write Triggers and Setters for a TreeView through C# rather than XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969139/how-to-write-triggers-and-setters-for-a-treeview-through-c-sharp-rather-than-xam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var colorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
treeNode.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, colorBrush);
```

Comment: thanks done it using similar statements        SolidColorBrush colorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue);                    treeNode.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, colorBrush);