# WPF Treeview loses focus when Context Menu is open

Tags: wpf, focus, contextmenu

A TreeView in Visual Studio (Solution Explorer, for example) has the following behavior:

- if the TreeView has focus, selected item is highlighted with blue;
- if  focus moves from TreeView, selected item becomes gray;
- if context menu is opened on item, the item becomes blue **and remains blue while context menu is on the screen**

But in WPF stock TreeView, item's context menu steals focus from TreeView, and selected item becomes gray when context menu is shown. Howewer, window menu behaves properly and does not steal focus.

How do I make my program act like VS? I know I can tweak the inactive highlight brush to be blue, but in this case selected item would not become gray when TreeView **really** loses focus.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3031192/773118) answer. Seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `Focusable` property on each `ContextMenuItem` and on the `ContextMenu` itself to `False` and you will get what you want :

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Item1">                
                <MenuItem Header="Sub Item 1"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Sub Item 2"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Sub Item 3"></MenuItem>                                    
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Item2">
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Item 1"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Item 2"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Item 3"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <TreeView Grid.Row="1">
        <TreeView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Focusable="False">
                <MenuItem Header="Ctx1" Focusable="False"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Ctx2" Focusable="False"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Ctx3" Focusable="False"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <TreeViewItem Header="ItemOne">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Item 2"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Item 3"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>        
</Grid>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This solution seems fine on a first glance, but has a drawback: since the real focus remains on TreeView, pressing arrow keys on keyboard causes navigation on the TreeView, instead of Context Menu.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this is due to the default style for `TreeViewItem` having a trigger on the `Selector.IsSelectionActive` attached property.  If you change this so that it triggers off `IsFocused` instead, I think you'll get the behavior you're after.

It works, because while the `ContextMenu` takes away keyboard focus (and causes `IsSelectionActive` to be set to false), the original window retains it's logical focus.

Here is a style I created in Visual Studio by right-clicking an "off the shelf" `TreeViewItem` in the designer, and clicking "Edit Template", "Edit a Copy...".  I then replaced `Selector.IsSelectionActive` with `IsFocused`.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Fill" Color="#FF595959"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Stroke" Color="#FF262626"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Stroke" Color="#FF27C7F7"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Fill" Color="#FFCCEEFB"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Stroke" Color="#FF1CC4F7"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Fill" Color="#FF82DFFB"/>
<PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Fill" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Stroke" Color="#FF818181"/>
<Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="16">
                    <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Fill}" Stroke="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Stroke}">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Fill}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Fill}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```